# Assign ASCII values to variable in shell

Tags: shell, variables, ascii, assign

I'm still new at shell scripting

I want to assign * to a variable an print it. Write now I'm just printing it with:

```
echo -e "\052"
```

Is there a way to assign that value to a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(cmd)` or `` `cmd` `` to capture a command's output. The `$(...)` form is preferred because it's easier to nest.

```
var=$(echo -e "\052")
```

The shell will interpret escape sequences inside `$'...'`. That's single quotes with a dollar sign in front.

```
var=$'\052'
```

Or of course you could write the asterisk directly. Quote it to prevent wildcard expansion.

```
var='*'
```

When you print it, [make sure to quote the variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html). It's annoying to always have to type double quotes any time you use a variable, but it's usually the right thing to do.

```
echo "$var"    # yes
echo $var      # no
```

Comment: Best advice is from the bottom up.

Answer (score 0):

Using backticks, ``, allows you to capture the output of a command. Many shells have a more sophisticated syntax, `$()`. But backticks are the most portable.

```
var=`echo -e "\052"`
```